# Efficient Ways to Load Large data Sets

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am reading a white paper on MapReduce by Google. And I want to know how to pass GBs of data efficiently to MapReduce algorithm. The paper shows stats for processing TBs of data in seconds. This paper says that to make it work effieciently they reduce the network calls and try to make local writes on local disks. Only the reducer function performs the remote calls and writes olocal outputfile. Now when we load GBs of data in memory to pass it to a Map function, the data loader application will would certainly go out of memory.

So my question is what techniques should be used to load data efficiently and pass to scheduler applications for M and R schedulings and to calculate the number of M pieces and R pieces.

I would most probably reading some data from the Oracle database and update it back in some other tables.

URL to white paper 
http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf

Comment: why would you load everything into memory?

Answer (score 0):

In Google's case the data is likely stored in GFS which is a distributed file system, and the map phase is run on nodes that double as GFS storage nodes. This way  the system mostly uses data that's already on local disks, so the bulk of data does not have to be moved over the network.

There's a paper on GFS too: http://research.google.com/archive/gfs.html

Comment: @ Joni : I don't think so that Google would be keeping data of whole of the world on each systems local disk. They might be extracting data from somewhere the placing on each cluster member's local disk for map reduce to work on it. If this is the case then how data is extracted ?

Comment: Did you read the GFS whitepaper? Data is stored in  chunks, copies of each chunk are stored on 3 different nodes for high availability. Restoring petabytes of data from tertiary storage for map-reduce probably incurs a high latency so I don't think they do that.

Comment: I read HDFS for Hadoop which is almost copy of GFS. But I will read GFS too and then will have discussion with u If I need it.